# python ldap распространение схемы samba на пользователя

Tags: python, ldap

Описание : есть сервер Centos 7.4  на нем установлен openldap 2.4.44, создан домен "test.rdi" администратор домена "manager", в ldap добавлена схема samba, в которой в свою очередь убрана привязка к sambasid. В домене заведен пользователь testuser. Я начал писать скрипт который делал бы поиск определенных пользователей по логину и в случае нахождения его в базе добавлял бы ему новый objectclass sambaSamaccount и два атрибута sambaLMPassword и sambaNTPassword , а также заменял поле пароль.  По причине плохого знания ldap я смог только подключиться к серверу и сделать поиск.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ldap
ip_ldap ='ldap://192.168.59.239'
nt='8846f7eaee8fb117ad06bdd830b7586c'
lm='e52cac67419a9a224a3b108f3fa6cb6d'
ssha='{SSHA}dxedyX796NFkdcJ81iVOGycB1pc4J2TM'
manager_passwd = raw_input('enter ldap admin pass \n')
uid_manager ="cn=Manager,dc=test,dc=rdi"
dn = "dc=test,dc=rdi"
login = "testuser"
uid='(uid={0})'.format(login)
uid_user_people = 'uid=testuser,ou=People,dc=test,dc=rdi'
def ldap_search (ip_ldap,manager_passwd,uid_manager,dn):
    con = ldap.initialize(ip_ldap)
    con.simple_bind_s(uid_manager, manager_passwd)
    result = con.search_s(uid_user_people, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, )
    return result
a = ldap_search (ip_ldap, manager_passwd, uid_manager, dn)
print a
```

Вопрос : Как с помощью питона добавлять objectclass и атрибуты на пользователя, а также как их менять?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Коротко о том, что такое LDAP**

Во-первых, это стандартизированный протокол. Да, он так и называется Легковесный Протокол Доступа к Каталогам (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol). На практике это может означать следующее, что не возникнет проблем (или почти не возникнет), когда вы задумаете поменять реализацию LDAP-а (сервер бэкенда). Ваши интерфейсы работы с LDAP-сервером останутся неизменными.

Во-вторых, это способ хранения данных. В этом месте многие пытаются сравнивать LDAP с классическими sql-ными СУБД, но мы это делать не будем, т.к. это приведёт к дилемме - «забить мне гвоздь микроскопом или молотком».

В-третьих, это способ получения данных. Основной ориентацией LDAP-а является принцип: «один раз записал – много раз прочитал». Не нужно пытаться делать из LDAP-а «базу данных для биллинга» с тысячами «инсертов/апдейтов/делитов» - это не его задача.

**Коротко о структуре**

Каталог LDAP состоит из записей (*records*). Каждая запись имеет уникальное (отличительное) имя DN (*Distinguished Name*). Это имя может выглядеть, например, так: `cn=Василий Пушкин,ou=Personal,o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com`. В каталоге не может быть двух записей с одинаковыми DN. Части DN, разделенные запятой, называются RDN (*Relative Distinguished Name*). RDN тоже должен быть уникален, но только в рамках своего «уровня» («пути»). 
Как это понимать?

Из примера выше: RDN = `cn=Василий Пушкин`, следовательно не может быть еще одной записи с таким же RDN на «уровне» `ou=Personal,o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com`. Но никто не запрещает иметь запись с этим RDN на «уровне» `ou=Personal,o=Харчевня у Василия,dc=example,dc=com`. Также никто не запрещает иметь запись с этим RDN в таком виде: `cn=Василий Пушкин,o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com`. Тут мы просто поместили Василия в «корень» `o=Рога и копыта`. При этом Василий, «принадлежащий» `ou=Personal, o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com` и другой Василий (работающий в  корпорации `o=Харчевня у Василия`) никак не мешают друг другу.

Такая организация данных позволяет представить все записи в виде дерева, как это обычно и принято делать на практике.

Все DN-ы, перечисленные выше, можно изобразить в виде такого дерева:

```
dc=example,dc=com
    |_ o=Рога и копыта
    |   |_ ou=Personal
    |   |   |_ cn=Василий Пушкин
    |   |_ cn=Василий Пушкин
    |_ o=Харчевня у Василия
        |_ ou=Personal
            |_ cn=Василий Пушкин
```

Что это за непонятные аббревиатуры dc, ou, o и т.д. из которых состоят записи LDAP-а?

Чтобы не усложнять данный текст, представим, что это «объекты» структуры, которые являются хранилищами информации (данных). Эти «объекты» наследуются от специальных классов (`objectClasses`) и содержат наборы атрибутов (`attributes`). В атрибутах записывается необходимая для хранения информация. Атрибуты могут содержать много значений (например, такой как, `memberUid`), а также есть такие, которые обязаны определяться только один раз (например, `gidNumber`).

**Теперь к практической части**

Дабы не усложнять текст, предположим, что у нас настроен и запущен LDAP сервер и с ним можно работать. Но сам каталог пустой, т.е. нет никаких записей.

**Добавление записи**

Мы хотим добавить запись (из примера выше): `cn=Василий Пушкин,ou=Personal,o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com`.

Добавляем новую запись:

```
add_record = [('objectClass', ['person']), ('sn', ['Пушкин'])]
l.add_s('cn=Василий Пушкин,ou=Personal,o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com', add_record)
```

… и обламываемся с ошибкой: `ldap.NO_SUCH_OBJECT: {'matched': 'dc=example,dc=com', 'desc': 'No such object'}`

Почему это произошло?

Как мы помним, каталог у нас совершенно пустой. Фактически в нем, кроме «корня», ничего нет. Поэтому добавляя в каталог запись (DN) из пяти RDN-ов, ошибка возникает на моменте определения первого от корня RDN -  `o=Рога и копыта`.

Дело в том, что LDAP сам не занимается созданием несуществующих «объектов» в каталоге, пытаясь догадаться, что же это за тип записи подразумевал пользователь. Это ключевой момент (и как показывает практика – для многих самый непонятный) при добавлении новой записи в каталог.

В связи с этим вся ответственность за создание полного «пути» лежит на пользователе, который сам должен явно описать все необходимые данные (objectClass, attributes) для создаваемого объекта.

Поэтому правильной будет такая последовательность:

```
add_record = [('objectClass', ['organization'])]
l.add_s('o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com', add_record)

add_record = [('objectClass', ['organizationalUnit'])]
l.add_s('ou=Personal,o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com', add_record)

add_record = [('objectClass', ['person']), ('sn', ['Пушкин'])]
l.add_s('cn=Василий Пушкин,ou=Personal,o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com', add_record)
```

**Удаление**

Это самое простое действие.

```
l.delete_s('cn=Василий Пушкин,ou=Personal,o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com')
```

Будет удален `cn=Василий Пушкин`, расположенный тут `ou=Personal,o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com`.

**Модификация**

Расширим запись Василия objectClass-ом `posixAccount`:

```
mod_attrs = [( ldap.MOD_ADD, 'objectClass', 'posixAccount' ), (ldap.MOD_ADD, 'uid', 'vasya' ), (ldap.MOD_ADD, 'uidNumber', '123'), (ldap.MOD_ADD, 'gidNumber', '321'), (ldap.MOD_ADD, 'hom
eDirectory', '/home/vasya')]
l.modify_s('cn=Василий Пушкин,ou=Personal,o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com', mod_attrs)
```

Класс `posixAccount` содержит 4 обязательных атрибута, поэтому их необходимо определить при модификации объекта.

**Поиск**

Найдем в компании «Рога и копыта» сотрудника с `uid` равным `vasya` и отобразим его домашний каталог.

```
basedn = "o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com"
searchFilter = "(uid=vasya)"
searchAttribute = ["homeDirectory"]
searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE 
ldap_result_id = l.search(basedn, searchScope, searchFilter, searchAttribute)
result_set = []
while 1:
    result_type, result_data = l.result(ldap_result_id, 0)
    if (result_data == []):
        break
    else:
        if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
            print result_data    # вывод результата полностью
            print result_data[0][1]['homeDirectory'][0]  # вывод homeDirectory
```

Теперь для наглядности можно собрать все описанные действия в один алгоритм:

создадим новую запись, модифицируем ее, найдем и удалим

```
import ldap

l = ldap.initialize('ldap://ldap-server')

binddn = "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"  # учетка администратора (пример)
password = "AdMinPassvv0rd"
l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
l.simple_bind_s(binddn, password)

# добавление
add_record = [('objectClass', ['organization'])]
l.add_s('o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com', add_record)

add_record = [('objectClass', ['organizationalUnit'])]
l.add_s('ou=Personal,o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com', add_record)

add_record = [('objectClass', ['person']), ('sn', ['Пушкин'])]
l.add_s('cn=Василий Пушкин,ou=Personal,o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com', add_record)

# модификация
mod_attrs = [( ldap.MOD_ADD, 'objectClass', 'posixAccount' ), (ldap.MOD_ADD, 'uid', 'vasya' ), (ldap.MOD_ADD, 'uidNumber', '123'), (ldap.MOD_ADD, 'gidNumber', '321'), (ldap.MOD_ADD, 'hom
eDirectory', '/home/vasya')]
l.modify_s('cn=Василий Пушкин,ou=Personal,o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com', mod_attrs)

# поиск
basedn = "dc=example,dc=com"
searchFilter = "(uid=vasya)"
searchAttribute = ["homeDirectory"]
searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE 
ldap_result_id = l.search(basedn, searchScope, searchFilter, searchAttribute)
result_set = []
while 1:
    result_type, result_data = l.result(ldap_result_id, 0)
    if (result_data == []):
        break
    else:
        if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
            print result_data    # вывод результата полностью
            print result_data[0][1]['homeDirectory'][0]  # вывод homeDirectory

# удаление
l.delete_s('cn=Василий Пушкин,ou=Personal,o=Рога и копыта,dc=example,dc=com')

l.unbind_s()
```

Надеюсь, что это поможет.

Comment: а можно чуть подробней, а то я получил ошибку:        "ldap.NO_SUCH_OBJECT: {'matched': u'dc=test,dc=rdi', 'desc': u'No such object'}"

Comment: @Андрей хм... подробней тут как бы и нечего сказать. `NO_SUCH_OBJECT` - `Нет Такого Объекта` ни больше, ни меньше. У вас в ошибке написано, что `dn = 'dc=test,dc=rdi'`. Напишите, то вы пытались в корне структуры делать .

Comment: `def ldapadd (ip_ldap,manager_passwd,uid_manager,dn): <br/>    con = ldap.initialize(ip_ldap)  <br/>
con.simple_bind_s(uid_manager, manager_passwd)  <br/>
result = con.search_s(uid_user_people, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, ) <br/>
mod_attrs = [( ldap.MOD_ADD, 'objectClass', 'Person' )] <br/>
object_dn = 'cn=Иванов Иван,dc=test,dc=rdi' <br/>
con.modify_s(object_dn, mod_attrs)<br/>  result = con.search_s(uid_user_people, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, ) <br/>
con.unbind_s()  <br/>
ldapadd (ip_ldap, manager_passwd, uid_manager, dn)` <br/>

Comment: @Андрей написал в более расширенном варианте.

Comment: спасибо огромное