# Изменение атрибутов в Active Directory

Tags: java, python, windows, active-directory

Есть АД с 1000 пользователей, атрибуты к примеру как: имя, организация, город уже заполнены, есть excel файл с еще одним атрибутом. Вопрос как внести этот атрибут(info) в ад. Приветствуются любые способы PowerShell, python, java

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803030/python-ldap-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-samba-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F/). Возможно, что найдете подсказку.

Comment: Спасибо, информация прелестная. Допустим есть такая структура  CN=РД, OU=Сектор ,OU=Отдел,OU=Dom, DC=home, DC=ru. В OU=Dom вложено допустим 10 DN и в них по два. Как автоматизировать циклом проход по всем путям обращаясь к кажому CN. Либо возможно есть способ выгрузить всех CN и пройтись по ним?

Comment: Я бы примерно делал так: запускаю поиск с фильтром типа `(objectClass=organizationalPerson)`, путем поиска `basedn =OU=Dom, DC=home` и типом поиска `ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE`. Получаю список всех вложенных объектов и делаю с ними что мне надо.

Comment: @de_frag пока так:  `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Domain Users" -Recursive | where {$_.info -eq $null} | Set-ADUser -Add @{info = { ` получаю всех пользователей  рекурсивно по OU="Domain Users" (и всем вложенным) где атрибут инфо не заполнен, и тем самое интересное :) Допустим нахожу CN=Иванов Иван, с атрибутом info, есть   файл  *.csv в нем список  с именами и значениями атрибутов,  как циклично пройтись по всем CN  и применить к ним значения из файла?

Comment: Я не увлекаюсь PowerShell-ом, поэтому не подскажу.

Answer (score 0):

Если этот атрибут уже есть в схеме то можно подключится к службе каталогов по LDAP и внести изменения. Для этого можно использовать модуль [LDAP3](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/) для Python3. Если такого атрибута нет, то нужно расширять схему, но это делать я не рекомендую, поскольку черевато проблемами при обновлении версии схемы.

Comment: атрибут есть, для всех пользователей сейчас он не задан, если я вас правильно понял

Comment: У этой библиотеке есть туториал https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/tutorial.html где хорошо описано как с ней работать, хотя должен быть способ сделать это же через PS, но я не знаю как он работает

Comment: через PS сходу не нашел как решить, посмотрю спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашлось, просто атрибут info не виделся, к нему нужно было обратиться через   -OtherAttributes @{info=$_.info}